# WPF Listbox refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

### Problem

---

I have a *Listbox* control and when a user clicks a button they are able to add items to the control.

The issue I am having is that the *Listbox* control itself is not refreshing and displaying the new values that the user has added. I have debugged the code and the datasource is being updated with the new values.

Anyone have any ideas?

### Code

---

**The C#:**

```
    ObservableCollection<ITimeLineDataItem> listboxData = new ObservableCollection<ITimeLineDataItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<ITimeLineDataItem> ListBoxData
    {
        get
        {
            return listboxData;
        }
    }

public Live()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}

public void RefreshListbox()
{
    ListSrc.ItemsSource = null;

    //THE CODE GOES HERE WHERE I UPDATE THE DATASOURCE.

    ListSrc.ItemsSource = ListBoxData;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
    <Border BorderBrush="#d6786a" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="15" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ListBox x:Name="ListSrc" Background="#ececec" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListBoxData}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="4" Margin="15"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
    </Border>
```

Comment: is your c# code a viewmodel or code behind?

Comment: Just bind ItemsSource to ListBoxData and add the items to ListBoxData. If you need to clear it, clear it. Let it notify the ListBox. That's what ObservableCollection is for, that's what it does. Don't thrash around with all this weird stuff in code behind. If you really want to replace ListBoxData, implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel and call OnPropertyChanged("ListBoxData") when the value of ListBoxData changes.

Comment: @adminSoftDK Code behind.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am not using ViewModel's in my project.

Comment: @BenClarke Using view models is easy and it makes stuff like this incredibly trivial. But it's your life.

Comment: @EdPlunkett This was an existing application that was built not using it. I am just adding functionality.

Comment: @BenClarke Ouch, that's ugly. I know that situation too well. But if the contents of the ObservableCollection are being displayed in the ListBox, just let the ObservableCollection handle all the notifications. Remove both lines where your C# touches ItemsSource (it's possible that right there will fix everything). Your only interaction with the ListBox should be updating the contents of ListBoxData. In the code you provide you don't show what causes changes to the list. How does that part work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to refresh. If the new item is added correctly to the source it should be visible on the list. However, can you update your post with the button click event code?